# Is there any simple way or trick to express given signal using waveforms of sum of simple sinusoidal signals?

Tags: signal, fourier

We know that Fourier series for periodic signal \$y(t)\$ is given by

$$ y(t) = \sum\limits_{m=0}^{+\infty} a_m \cos(w_m t) + \sum\limits_{m=0}^{+\infty}b_m \sin(w_m t). \quad$$

y(t) is sinusoidal periodic signal with period **T**

[image]

> 1. How would you decompose the given signal into simple sinusoid?
> 2. If possible can anybody show me  waveforms of  fundamental and harmonics components for the given signal y(t)?

Comment: Throw it into some math tools fft function? If you are interested into the dirty math details behind such a function, you might be better asking that on a math related stack.

Comment: This is a pure math problem.

Comment: @MathieuL I edited the question. Is it possible to express the given signal using sum of other simple sinusoidal signals?

Comment: @pandu At first glance, I would say yes, it look like a square wave which doesn't have enough harmonics add together.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I edited the question. Is it possible to express the given signal using sum of other simple sinusoidal signals?

Comment: If the signal is periodic, then in theory you can decompose it into a Fourier series. What do you get if you run it through a Fourier transform?

Comment: @Roger I don't understand how to apply Fourier series / transform to get fundamental and harmonics.

Comment: What you're looking for is the [inverse discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).

Comment: @Dave I want to have the given signal to be decomposed into its fundamental and harmonics components. you are free to choose any way you wish to . I want waveforms or values of its harmonics components.

Comment: The wikipedia article on the [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) has the formulas to get the coefficients \$a_n\$ and \$b_n\$. \$a_1\$ and \$b_1\$ are the fundamental components and the other (\$n>1\$) coefficients are the harmonics.

Comment: It's clearly periodic therefore it can be expressed as a Fourier series. I don't know what you mean by 'other simple sinusoidal signals'.

Comment: If your sampling rate divides evenly into the period, you can use any of the well-known ways of calculating a DFT to get the coefficients.

Comment: @Chu simple sinusoidal means fundamental and harmonics components from the Fourier series formula. can you show waveforms or expressions of the given signal?

Comment: @The Photon  can you show waveforms or expressions of the harmonics for the given signal?

Comment: @pandu, the nth harmonic is \$a_n\cos\left(\omega_n t\right)+b_n\sin\left(\omega_n t\right)\$ like you already gave in your post.

Comment: @The Photon as in your suggested wiki article, square wave is represented using sum of sinusoidal signals likewise could you represent the given signal waveform using sum of sinusoidal signals?

Comment: _...express given signal using sum of fundamental and harmonicsexpress given signal using sum of fundamental and harmonics...[is there] any other way than Fourier series?_  A sum of fundamental and harmonics _is_ a Fourier series.  You are asking whether there is any way to express the signal as a Fourier series without expressing it as a Fourier series.  Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @pandu, Not without access to your dataset. But even if you did share your dataset, this isn't a "do your work for you" website, it's a "teach you how to do it" website.

Comment: @pandu, 'simple sinusoidal means fundamental and harmonics components from the Fourier series formula' --- that's exactly what Fourier series is!

Answer (score 2):

Take the shortest repeating interval of the waveform - that seems to be one-quarter of what you have drawn - that is the time period of the fundamental frequency and, to find the amplitude of that fundamental, multiply that section of signal by a sine wave and a cosine wave of the same time period.

Then integrate (over the time period) the two multiplied waveforms to get two numbers. Divide those two numbers by the time period and you get the a and b coefficients that pertain to the fundamental signal. Well actually you get the RMS values so multiply them by 1.4142 to get the true a and b coefficients.

Repeat for the 2nd harmonic and keep going up in harmonics until you are satisfied there is no appreciable signal energy left to worth considering.

You can do it in excel if you have sample values for the repeating signal. If all you have is a picture then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anybody express given signal using sum of fundamental and harmonics?

The equation you gave is an expression of the signal in terms of the fundamental and harmonics.

\$a_n\cos\left(\omega t\right) + b_n\sin\left(\omega t\right)\$ is the \$n\$th harmonic. The fundamental is the same as the 1st harmonic.

The coefficients \$a_n\$ and \$b_n\$ can be calculated by formulas given in the Wikipedia article on the [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series).

You can easily plot an individual harmonic using the form

$$A \sin\left(\omega{}t +\phi\right) = a\cos\left(\omega{}t\right)+b\sin\left(\omega{}t\right)$$

with \$A=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\$ and \$\phi=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{a}{b}\$.